# How to use Bootstrap plugins in Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, plugins, nuxt.js

```json
"dependencies": {
  "ant-design-vue": "^1.7.2",
  "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
  "core-js": "^3.8.3",
  "nuxt": "^2.14.12",
  "popper.js": "^1.16.1"
}
```

I am trying to add bootstrap's plugins on my Nuxt.js project but it does not work, i checked my nuxt.config.js everything is ok and package.json are fine as well and i do not understand how it does not work.

Comment: Hi, what are you trying to do here exactly? What are the "plugins" you're trying to use here? Also, can you please share a [repro] or some code, even `package.json` and `nuxt.config.js`. We need to know what is not working and what you did so far. If it's not working, it may still come from the configuration, even if you think that everything is okay.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure on the nuxt config file like this

```
 modules: ['bootstrap-vue/nuxt']
```

by the way to add Bootstrap 5 with nuxt.js you can find it here https://github.com/Rasaf-Ibrahim/Vue.js-Boilerplates/tree/005